# Access var from a new swift file from a class

Tags: swift

I have this viewcontroller class:

```
class ThirdScreenViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
    
    var number = 1
    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        number = 2 
    }

}
```

And I have a different swift file. (Not another View Controller Class)

```
var newNumber = ThirdScreenViewController.number
```

This doesn't work. How can I access in my new swift file to this variable (2) from an other View Controller Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to make the property **static**:

```swift
class ThirdScreenViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
    
    static var number = 1
    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        ThirdScreenViewController.number = 2 
    }
}
```

After that you should be able to call the variable as indicated in your example:

```
var newNumber = ThirdScreenViewController.number
```

But using static properties in such a case is not the best practice.